# Spring Cloud Data Flow Apps not fetching external arguments and environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-skipper

I have specified External arguments and environment variables for an app deployed as a stream through Spring Cloud Data Flow.

But the application is not considering some of the env variables and parameters.

Im passing an external property called 'URL'. and the same property is available under resource folder of the springboot app as well. Ideally as per documentation the external property I passed should override the internal one. And this is not happening. It is always taking the internal one.

Tried multiple redeployment and restarts. Interestingly it was working fine for a long time. and its stopped working after a redeployment.

Comment: That error message is normal, if the app is a spring cloud config server client and there is no config server available (default endpoint localhost:8888).  Can you provide more details on the environment variable issue?

Comment: @dturanski, thanks for the response. Im passing an external property called 'URL'. and the same property is available under resource folder of the springboot app as well. Ideally as per documentation the external property i passed should override the internal one. And this is not happening. It is always taking the internal one.

Comment: Did you add any new jars to your pom.xml? Strangely, I faced the same issue and found that I had recently added a spring cloud data flow rest client jar that was the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @CKing I will cross check this and let you. For now I have applied a work around